# Using session token on plain HTTP Request on Parse's REST API

Tags: parse-platform

I am working with Parse.com REST API where my working environment restricts me from using modified header on GET requests.

For now, the GET request using plain http is served good, and we can login to the parse using url formatted like this:

```
https://ParseAppID:javascript-key=ParseJSKey@api.parse.com/1/login?username=someName&password=somePass
```

But we can't check if current session is valid, as with GET request formatted like this:

```
https://ParseAppID:javascript-key=ParseJSKey@api.parse.com/1/users/me
```

we received invalid session response

Is there any way to put session token as additional or replacement of javascript-key? Thanks

Comment: Choice of rest api makes no sense if there is not a method to set http headers